# Create line chart with X values in order as given

Tags: android, achartengine

Is it possible in `AChartEngine` to make a line chart with X values not always increasing? I think a picture describes what I mean best.

[image: Complete Line Chart]

In the picture above lines connect points with increasing X values (left to right), and decreasing X values (right to left).

Right now when I try to pass in this data to a line chart in `AChartEngine` it automatically sorts the points by their X values. I get something that looks like the following:

[image: Sorted X]

I would like to create a chart where the points are connected in the order they are given, even if that means drawing a *backwards* line. Is there a way to do this with `AChartEngine`?

Comment: ACE is intended for charting: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=247

Comment: So by the looks of it ACE used to not sort the X values in an XYSeries. Would it take much work to create a custom chart that would not sort the X's? What class would need to be extended or implemented?

Comment: That's correct. However, starting from Android 3.0, it is no longer fine to draw stuff outside the screen. This is why I have to sort the data and get only the values that are rendered inside the screen area.

Comment: So how can i plot a figure like above or a circle. Also Why Issue-247 hasn't been fixed till now. I want to plot circle and parabola etc, How can i use ACE. Should i stick to 0.7 version only ?